# Real time usecase scenarios of mvtolocal in HDFS

Tags: hdfs

There is a command mvtolocal in hdfs. If we use this command, data in hdfs will be removed and copied to local. As per my knowledge, data should not be modified once it is loaded into hdfs. In which cases/real time scenarios, do we need to use these commands. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, `-moveToLocal` does not work. It is not yet implement in Apache Hadoop.

Comment: Agreed with @franklinsijo.  Did you see documentation somewhere that talked about a "mvtolocal"?